# How to deserialize complex json string to python object?

Tags: python, json

I need to convert json string to python object. for example,

```
{
"person":{
    "name":"aa",
    "age":"12",
    "address":{
        "city":"cc",
        "road":"kk"
    }

    }    
}
```

there are two python class `Person` and `Address` used to generate python object. but I don't know how to map it.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the indicated question. This question specifically asks about complex (nested) structures, the other does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert the JSON string to a native Python dictionary with [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

d = json.loads(s)
```

It is not clear what arguments your `Person` and `Address` take, but if they take keyword arguments matching the dictionary content it could be as simple as:

```
d['address'] = Address(**d['address'])
p = Person(**d)
```

Where `**` unpacks the dictionary into keyword arguments.

Comment: This won't work with nested classes, nor when you don't a c'tor the takes all these arguments. I would recommend [jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.github.io/)

Comment: @gMorphus *"if they take keyword arguments matching the dictionary content"*

Comment: my bad... still the rest of my comment stands.

Answer (score -3):

You can do this in a couple ways.  One way is the simplejson literal translation.  I would say the cleanest way of creating an extensible method is creating a class with that same structure.

Comment: This really doesn't help the OP... (also not a very good suggestion).